# How to add a JProgressBar which works with a Timer in my code?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, jprogressbar

I want to add a JProgressBar in my code, which counts till 5 (in seconds). After that, it shall make new values, but my current problem is, that I can't even make the ProgressBar with my ActionListener, so I doesn't repeat. Can someone show me how to add the ProgressBar with the Timer?

I tried to add it in the Haupt class, but it didn't repeat after pressing the restart button (Neustart), so I tried many other things, but nothing worked.

```java
/**
 * @author (Noah Steinle) 
 * @version (2.2.1)
 */

//Importe
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

//Klasse mit JFrame erweitert und hat einen ActionListener implementiert
public class Haupt extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    private int x = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    private int y = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    private int z = x * y;  

    private JTextField benutzerWert;   

    private JLabel aufgabe;
    private JLabel eingabeTipp;    
    private JButton neustartButton;

    private static int richtig;
    private JLabel richtigLabel;

    private static int falsch;
    private JLabel falschLabel;

    private Timer timer;

    private JProgressBar progressBar;


    public Haupt() 
    {
        super("Multi-Game");

        //nutzt FlowLayout ein
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Label zur Anzeige des Aufgabeterms
        aufgabe = new JLabel(x + "\u2219" + y + "= ");  
        add(aufgabe);

        //Eingabefeld für Benutzer und wird gecheckt
        benutzerWert = new JTextField(5); 
        benutzerWert.addActionListener(this);
        add(benutzerWert);

        //gibt einen Tipp aus, wie der Wert im Vergleich zum Ergebnis ist
        eingabeTipp = new JLabel("");
        add(eingabeTipp); 

        //Neustart
        neustartButton = new JButton("Nächste Aufgabe");
        add(neustartButton);
        neustartButton.addActionListener(this);

        //Anzahl der Richtigen        
        richtig = 0;
        richtigLabel = new JLabel();
        richtigLabel.setText("Anzahl der Richtigen: " + richtig);
        add(richtigLabel);

        //Anzahl der Falschen
        falsch = 0;
        falschLabel = new JLabel();
        falschLabel.setText("Anzahl der Falschen: " + falsch);
        add(falschLabel);

        //ProgressBar erstellen
        progressBar =new JProgressBar(0,5); //min = 0 , max = 5
        add(progressBar);
    }  

    //Methode zum Generieren von Zufallswerten im Bereich von 1 bis 20
    private int zufallWert()
    {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 20 +1);
        return x;
    }




     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
     {
           //Reaktion auf Benutzereingabe
           if(e.getSource()==benutzerWert) {

             int versuch;

             //String (benutzerWert) in Integer umwandeln + in Versuch einf.
             versuch = Integer.parseInt(benutzerWert.getText());


             if (versuch > z) 
             {
                  eingabeTipp.setText("Zu groß!");
                  SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(eingabeTipp);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  falsch++;
                  falschLabel.setText("Falsche: " + falsch);
             }

             if (versuch < z) 
              {
                  eingabeTipp.setText("Zu klein!");
                  SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(eingabeTipp);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                  falsch++;
                  falschLabel.setText("Falsche: " + falsch);
              }             

             if (versuch == z) 
              {
                  eingabeTipp.setText("Richtig!!!");
                  //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(eingabeTipp);
                  benutzerWert.setEditable(true);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  richtig++;
                  richtigLabel.setText("Richtige : " + richtig);
                  x = zufallWert();
                  y =zufallWert();
                  z = x * y;
                  aufgabe.setText(x + "\u2219" + y);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  benutzerWert.setText("");
                  eingabeTipp.setText("");
              }      
           }

           //Button setzt neue Werte
           else
           {
               x = zufallWert();
               y =zufallWert();
               z = x * y;
               aufgabe.setText(x + "\u2219" + y);
               getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
               eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
               aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
               benutzerWert.setText("");
           }
     } 

    //Anzeigen des JFrames
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Haupt ausgabeFrame = new Haupt();
        ausgabeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ausgabeFrame.setSize(550, 150);
        ausgabeFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If the answer is right, it should add 1 to "Richtige" else to "Falsche", if the timer is at 5, while trying to answer the question, it should skip to the next question (so new values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out and wanted to share my solution:

```java
/**
 * @author (Noah Steinle) 
 * @version (2.3.1)
 */

//Importe
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

//Klasse mit JFrame erweitert und hat einen ActionListener implementiert
public class Haupt extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private int x = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    private int y = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    private int z = x * y;  

    private JTextField benutzerWert;   

    private JLabel aufgabe;
    private JLabel eingabeTipp;    
    private JButton neustartButton;

    private static int richtig;
    private JLabel richtigLabel;

    private static int falsch;
    private JLabel falschLabel;

    private Timer timer;

    private int counter;

    private JProgressBar progressBar;


    public Haupt()
    {
        super("Multi-Game");

        //nutzt FlowLayout ein
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Label zur Anzeige des Aufgabeterms
        aufgabe = new JLabel(x + "\u2219" + y + "= ");
        add(aufgabe);

        //Eingabefeld für Benutzer und wird gecheckt
        benutzerWert = new JTextField(5);
        benutzerWert.addActionListener(this);
        add(benutzerWert);

        //gibt einen Tipp aus, wie der Wert im Vergleich zum Ergebnis ist
        eingabeTipp = new JLabel("");
        add(eingabeTipp);

        //Neustart
        neustartButton = new JButton("Naechste Aufgabe");
        add(neustartButton);
        neustartButton.addActionListener(this);

        //Anzahl der Richtigen
        richtig = 0;
        richtigLabel = new JLabel();
        richtigLabel.setText("Anzahl der Richtigen: " + richtig);
        add(richtigLabel);

        //Anzahl der Falschen
        falsch = 0;
        falschLabel = new JLabel();
        falschLabel.setText("Anzahl der Falschen: " + falsch);
        add(falschLabel);

        //ProgressBar wird erstellt
        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0,5); //min = 0 , max = 5
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        add(progressBar);
        
        //Timer wird erstellt
        timer = new Timer(5000, this); //Timer mit 5 Sekunden
          
           timer.start();
           new Timer(1000, updateProBar).start();
    }  

    ActionListener updateProBar = new ActionListener() 
    {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) 
       {
          //ProgressBar wird veraendert
          progressBar.setValue(++counter);
          if(progressBar.getValue() == 5) 
          {
             counter = 0;
          }
       }
    };
    
    
    //Methode zum Generieren von Zufallswerten im Bereich von 1 bis 20
    private int zufallWert()
    {
       int x = (int) (Math.random() * 20 +1);
       return x;
    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
           //Reaktion auf Benutzereingabe
           if(e.getSource()==benutzerWert) {

             int versuch;

             //String (benutzerWert) in Integer umwandeln + in Versuch einf.
             versuch = Integer.parseInt(benutzerWert.getText());

             //wenn Eingabe groesser als Ergebnis
             if (versuch > z)
             {
                  eingabeTipp.setText("Zu gross!");
                  SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(eingabeTipp);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  falsch++;
                  falschLabel.setText("Falsche: " + falsch);
             }
             //wenn Eingabe geringer als Ergebnis
             if (versuch < z)
              {
                  eingabeTipp.setText("Zu klein!");
                  SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(eingabeTipp);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                  falsch++;
                  falschLabel.setText("Falsche: " + falsch);
              }
             //wenn Ergebnis erraten
             if (versuch == z)
              {
                  eingabeTipp.setText("Richtig!!!");
                  //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(eingabeTipp);
                  benutzerWert.setEditable(true);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  richtig++;
                  richtigLabel.setText("Richtige : " + richtig);
                  x = zufallWert();
                  y =zufallWert();
                  z = x * y;
                  aufgabe.setText(x + "\u2219" + y);
                  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                  eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  benutzerWert.setText("");
                  eingabeTipp.setText("");
                  counter = 0;
                  progressBar.setValue(0);
                  timer.restart();
              }
           }

           //Button setzt neue Werte und Timer bzw. ProgressBar auch
           else
           {
               x = zufallWert();
               y =zufallWert();
               z = x * y;
               aufgabe.setText(x + "\u2219" + y);
               getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
               eingabeTipp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
               aufgabe.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
               benutzerWert.setText("");
               counter = 0;
               progressBar.setValue(0);
               timer.restart();
           }
     } 
     
    //Anzeigen des JFrames
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Haupt ausgabeFrame = new Haupt();
        ausgabeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ausgabeFrame.setSize(550, 150);
        ausgabeFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the [JProgressBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) display something, set it to a specific value when your button is pressed:

```
if(e.getSource()==benutzerWert) { // below this line, add

  int anzahlAntworten = falsch + richtig;
  progressBar.setValue(anzahlAntworten);
  if (anzahlAntworten > 5) {
    // whatever should happen if the end of the progressBar is reached, maybe reset? or GameOver?
  } 
  // ...
```

}

The [Timer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_scheduleatfixedrate.htm) can be created in your main method, so it calls a run-method at a fixed interval (e.g. once every second). See the example in the link above. You probably want to change the progressBar value in your run-method.

Comment: Thank you very much :D
but the problem is, that it should count up to 5 and then restart, but I can't mannage it to do it

Comment: Can't you just put a `if (anzahlAntworten>5) { falsch = 0; richtig = 0; progressBar.setValue(0);}` in there?

Comment: No, you misunderstood me, I just want to increase "Falsche" if the timer is over. And the progressbar shall show the time (1-5 seconds)

Comment: Actually, it's not even so important to increase "Falsche" the main problem is to create the timer for the progressbar and let them work together

Comment: Ok, then put your `x = zufallWert() ...` section where you generate a new task in a seperate method and call that whenever the timer calls `run()` and the seconds passed equals five. Add to that method that the progressBar is reset. If seconds passed is smaller than five, increase seconds passed.

Comment: Have you read the link for Timer i've provided in the answer? It shows a quite short example on how to use the Timer.

Comment: Maybe post the code that - to the best of your knowledge- should work, but doesn't? Edit your original question